# How to get any type of parms in rust

Tags: rust

I added the [`read_input`](https://crates.io/crates/read_input) crate to my dependencies and wrote the following code:

```rust
let username: String = input().repeat_msg("Please input your name: ").get();
```

When I try to print it in the terminal, it prints what I've inputted, but when I try to consume it through a function:

```
pub fn sub(values: String) {
  //  code
}
```

I can't take it in, it says I've given it a `()` type variable when it explicitly says in the top `String`, so I was wondering if I can maybe get the text out of the input some how by converting or some way, or in the function being able to get any type of params.

So I want to know a way to get any type of params in a function, it can be a `i32` or a `String` or how to convert the `()` type variable to `String`.

full code

maint.rs:

```
use read_input::prelude::*;
mod sub;
use sub::lexar;

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome Rice Lang");
    let mut done = false;
    let ctrldkey = false;
    while !done {
        let mut input: String = input().msg("> ").get();
        println!("{}", input);
        if ctrldkey == true {
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

sub.rs:

```
pub fn sub(values: String) {
    print!("{}", values)
}
```

Error:

```
input = sub(input);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `()`
```

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Comment: To expand a bit, if the first code line given in the question compiles, then `username` is of type `String`, and you can pass it to any function accepting a `String`, so `sub(username)` will work. Since you get a compiler error, you must be doing something else we don't know about yet.

Comment: I've added the full code, check it out

Comment: Isn't it that you loose ownership of the variable after you print it?

Comment: @imagineeedev show the version of the code that doesn't work not the version that does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not that you are unable to call the function. If you were to try to do this instead:

```rust
sub(input);
```

Then it would work. Which means you can call the function. The problem is that you are trying to assign to `input` what the function returns. But the function returns nothing also known as `()`. And the `input` variable is actually a `String` so you can only put a `String` to it.

Example of assigning wrong type to a variable will give a similar error as you got:

```rust
let mut input = String::from("example string");

// this gives an error because we are trying to
// put a non-String value into input
input = 6;
```

To have a function that returns a type other than `()` (which is the default) you have to specify the return type like so:

```rust
fn this_returns_a_string() -> String {
    String::from("from function")
}

let mut input = String::from("example string");

// this will work
input = this_returns_a_string();
```

Comment: I will edit my answer once the question becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: @kmdreko I think you are right I don't think I will do it again but removing it now after the OP has seen it might be even worse.